# Survey Monkey API getting Remote server returned an error : 403 forbidden and X-mashery error code: ERR_403_Service_Requires_SSLage

Tags: c#, surveymonkey

Here is my c# code. I am trying to pull data from my survey monkey for my company, have access key and token. Please I need your help/suggestions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Servicetest
{
    public class Program
    {


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string urlAuth =
            "http://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_response_counts?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


    //    const string contentType = "application/json";

        const string contentType = "text/xml";

       // System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        try
        {
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlAuth) as HttpWebRequest;

            const string token =
                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";

            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = "POST";

                webRequest.ContentType = contentType;

                webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "bearer" + token;

                var responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

                if (responseReader != null)
                {
                    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                    responseReader.Close();

                    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

                    Console.Write(responseData);

                }




            }
        }

        catch (System.Net.WebException exc)
        {
            if ((exc.Response is System.Net.HttpWebResponse) &&
                (exc.Response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                Console.Write("401");
            else
                throw exc;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: So what is it thsat is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's best when you have a 3rd party problem to ask the 3rd party.  If this was specific to C#, which it's not, then it would be appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 3rd party error message (regardless if it can be solved using basic logic).

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint requires SSL, simply change your url from http:// to https://, i.e. https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_response_counts?api_key=xxxxxxxxx